# Character set encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

All, Im having the age old problem with character encoding...

I have a mySQL DB with a field set to `utf8_unicode_ci`. My PHP page as the header entry `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. When I use a simple form to POST data with Cyrillic characters to the DB, e.g. 'гыдлпоо', the characters display correctly in the textarea, and are added to the DB where they display correctly.

When fetching the characters from the DB, my page only displays a series of question marks. I've used `mb_detect_encoding($content, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1", true);` and the content is UTF-8, however the characters do not display.

I've searched around (including on SO) and tried any number of solutions, to no avail- any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried using SET NAMES 'utf8' query before fetching data from DB?

Comment: This has me closer to where I need to be...I've read the method shouldnt be used however- is this correct?

Comment: you can alternatively use mysql_set_charset() function - at least they say in the manual that it's the preferred way http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: just in case, can you please post your table definition? you can get it by executing query SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`

Comment: this worked- if you post it as an answer i'll award you as the answerer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)() function before fetching data from database.

Answer (score 3):

Do this right after mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db():

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: is there an equivalent for connections via PDO?

Answer (score 2):

did you try to use the form with

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

?
this might help.. it's not necessary for the text to be readable in your database.. when they are saved they should be utf8 encoded.. you need them to look fine when you output the string again

Comment: No joy- when displaying there are no question marks anymore - but the result still isnt there: �? �?омпании (should be О Компании)